# How do I create a regular expression that wont match a line with a sub string 'ac' but can have 'ac' at the end?

Tags: regex

I have the rules that L can be {abxac where x is any string of a's, b's, and c's but can not contain the sub string ac. The current regular expression I have is:

```
^(ab)[a,b,c]+(ba)$
```

I've tried  things like:

```
^(ab)[a,b,c]+[^b\a](ba)$
```

Comment: Which Regex are you using (Tool/program) ?

Comment: Also please add examples of input, both valid and invalid with expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With every repeated character, use negative lookahead for `ac`, and then you can have an optional group at the end for `ac`:

```
^ab(?:(?!ac)[abc])*(?:ac)?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/p9mVJq/2

To use a character set, don't separate each character you want to allow with commas - instead, just put each literal character right next to each other, like `[abc]` in the regex above. (don't use `[a,b,c]` unless you want to permit commas in the string as well, and in that case, put only one of each unique character in the character set, eg `[abc,]`)